# Tkinter, class, and calling external python program

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program called main.py:

```
def prog2():
exec(open("prog2.py").read())

buttonHMI = tk.Button(text="Program HMI", width=15, font=("Arial", 14), command=prog2)
buttonHMI.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=1, padx=20, pady=10, sticky=W)
```

So there's 1 button and when pressed it executes a 2nd program called prog2:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()

def close():
    window.destroy

CB1 = Checkbutton(window, text="Enable VNC", font=("Arial", 12), variable=action_VNC)
CB1.grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=10)
CB1.configure(bg='#34aeeb')

ButtonClose= tk.Button(window, text="Close", width=20, font=("Arial", 14), command=window.destroy)
ButtonClose.grid(columnspan=2, column = 3, row=9, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, window=None):
        self.sv = tk.StringVar()
        
        ButtonShow = tk.Button(window, text="Program HMI", width=20, font=("Arial", 14), command=self.actions)
        ButtonShow.grid(columnspan=2, row=9, column = 0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

        progress = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 500, mode = 'determinate')
        progress.grid(row=10, columnspan = 4, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

        outText = Text(window, width=50, height=20, wrap=WORD)
        outText.grid(row=11, columnspan=4, padx=10)
        
        
###########################################################
#start actions.  
    def actions(self):
        print("action")


Timer()

window.mainloop()
```

The problem I'm having is from main.py, I open prog2, some of the objects (Buttonshow, progress, outText) will show up in the main.py window.  But CB1 and Close objects will show in prog2.  If I execute prog2.py by itself, then all the objects will show correctly in prog2 window.  How do I get all of prog2 objects to show in prog2?

Comment: Use `Timer(window)` instead.  But multiple instances of `Tk()` should be avoided.

Comment: `exec(open("prog2.py").read())` smells like an `import` would have been the right thing...

Comment: you sure seond program runs ? CB1 = Checkbutton(window, text="Enable VNC", font=("Arial", 12), variable=action_VNC)

NameError: name 'action_VNC' is not defined

Comment: @pippo1980 - yes it works.  I forgot to post that that function called action_VNC.  It does work though.  Biggest problem is I have some objects in Prog2 showing up in main.py.

Comment: @acw1668 - Sorry for the noob question but how do I use Timer(window)?  Something like 'def__int__(self, Timer(window)): '  or 'Class Timer(window)'?    Won't I need multiple TK() if I wanted to make multiple windows in tkinter?  Prog2.py started off as an independent program.   Now I created main.py to run prog2.py and other "formerly independent" programs off of it.

Comment: I think @acw1668 meant that you replace your current line of `Timer()` with `Timer(window)`. To create new windows use `Toplevel` widget. You should still use `import` for importing stuff from other python files

Comment: I am a noob too, both python and especially tkinter, but take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application, upvote it if you find it interesting  or https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#the-window-manager

Comment: @acw1668 - If I called multiple instances of tk() in the same file, I'd get that it's bad, but these are 2 separate files, is this still bad?

Comment: @Matiiss - I did and I got a different error.  I get a NameError:  name 'window' is not defined.

Basically I can run scripts off a 2nd python prog, but I can't run a "2nd instance" of tkinter?